# Gradle error when Update to Android studio 3.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.2

I updated my Android Studio version to 3.2. Now I am facing following error for my project - `com.novoda.gradle.release.AndroidLibrary$LibraryUsage.getDependencyConstraints()Ljava/util/Set`;

Currently I am using gradle version 4.6.
Issue link https://github.com/novoda/bintray-release/issues/177 says to downgrade gradle version to 4.4 but minimum supported version for Android Studio 3.2 is 4.6.

How to resolve this error.

Answer (score 25):

I solved the same error by changing the order of the plugins in your build.gradle file to :

```
//has to be BEFORE 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.novoda.bintray-release' 
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

The solution is stated here - [Take a look at : Issue III](https://medium.com/@anitaa_1990/6-easy-steps-to-upload-your-android-library-to-bintray-jcenter-59e6030c8890).

While keeping the `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip` in my gradle-wrapper.properties file.

Answer (score 3):

This solution worked for me:
As Bintray has fixed the issue in its new release i.e. 0.9 so adding that in build.gradle (project) files removes the error.

classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.9'

Answer (score 0):

You will either need to downgrade back to AS 3.1.x or attempt the workarounds described on the Novoda issue you linked. Namely [this plugin](https://github.com/StefMa/bintray-release)...

Comment: "A super duper easy way to release your Android and Java artifacts to Bintray." This plugin is to upload your module to bintray, that not I want.

Anyways I tried but didn't worked.