# Problem at buiding old project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have a problem at building my project in Android Studio, these are the main errors.

```
 org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':library'.
 Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.novoda.gradle.release.AndroidLibrary$LibraryUsage.getDependencyConstraints()Ljava/util/Set;
```

In Build tree there are errors in Build > run build > configure build > Configure project: library.

Is this a problem with new SDK or libraries configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to change the order of the plugins in your build.gradle file to :

```
//has to be BEFORE 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.novoda.bintray-release' 
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

Stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52495168/gradle-error-when-update-to-android-studio-3-2')